# How to fix "undefined reference to createList"

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I'm writing a program that a user can create singly linked-list and enter student information into the list, but I'm getting an error saying "undefined referance to createList", how do i fix this error?

'''

```
struct student
{
    int id, age, choice;
    char name[30];
};

struct node
{
    struct student student_data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *prependNode(struct node *head);
/*void removeNextNode(struct node *node);*/

struct node *createList(void);

int main(void)
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    int choice;

    printf("Please select an option: ");
    printf("1. Create\n");
/*      printf("2. Display\n");
    printf("3. Insert\n");
    printf("4. Remove\n");
    printf("5. Search");
    printf("6. Exist");*/
    scanf("%d", &choice);

switch(choice)
{
    case 1:
        head = createList();
        break;
}

return 0;
}
```

'''

Comment: Hi @Jonathan Simon, if an answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: after adding the missing statement: `#include <stdio.h>`, the posted code compiles just fine.  Therefore, the problem your seeing is at link time.  However, you have not posted the rest of the code, nor your link command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared the function `createList` but not actually defined it anywhere.  You need to define the function, or tell the compiler/linker where the file/library is that does define it.

Declaration:

```
struct node *createList(void);
```

Definition:

```
struct node *createList(void)
{
    // implementation here
}
```